Как установить связь один к одному, без создания записи в таблице?
Предположим что есть таблица с ролями в которой 5 записей, я хочу сделать так что бы у меня пользователи ссылались на какую-то из этих записей,но я не знаю как это реализовать, ниже примеры
вот к примеру запись многие ко многим, с промежуточной таблицей, и в этом случае запись в таблице roles не нужно будет создавать каждый раз, а лишь запись в user_roles - как это реализовать но со связью один к одному ? Что бы у юзера была роль

мои предположения но с промежуточной таблицей, но мне кажется это каким-то не верным вариантом не знаю почему, потому что я явно хочу что бы у юзера была лишь 1 роль

без промежуточной таблицы, и без создания записи в таблице ролей, но зато у роли есть юзер а не наоборот, как в этом случае выбрать при запросе на получения юзера, получить ещё и его роль ? если связь в другом направлении


При конфигурации связи один-к-одному вам не нужна дополнительная таблица, всё что вам нужно для установки данной связи - это просто добавить ссылку (references) к одной из таблиц. Связь много-ко-многим требует наличия дополнительной таблицы, но связь один-к-одному - нет. В одну из таблиц добавьте столбец, который будет Внешним ключом к другой таблице. Вот пример реализации такой связи:
CREATE TABLE Пользователи (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    имя VARCHAR(50),
    email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Профили (
    id_профиля INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_пользователя INT UNIQUE REFERENCES Пользователи(id) not null,
    дата_рождения DATE,
    фото VARCHAR(100),
);

Тут стоит учесть, что связь один-к-одному осуществляется при помощи этой строчки кода:
id_пользователя INT UNIQUE

Если не указывать UNIQUE, это будет связь один-ко-многим. not null делает эту связь обязательной.
Ресурсы для изучения:

learnentityframeworkcore.com
entityframeworktutorial.net


При таком подходе
CREATE TABLE Пользователи (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
имя VARCHAR(50),
email VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE Профили (
id_профиля INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_пользователя INT UNIQUE REFERENCES Пользователи(id) not null,
дата_рождения DATE,
фото VARCHAR(100),
);
нужно будет создавать явно запись в профилях для каждого пользователя
я же хочу что бы в профилях было например 3 записи, и пользователи ссылались на эти записи
например 10 пользователей ссылаются на профиль 1

@llWebStylell, тогда это буде уже не связь один-к-одному, а один-ко-многим. При связи один-к-одному одному профилю будет соответствовать один запись пользователя и наоборот. Если вы хотите, что бы на один профиль можно было ссылать нескольким пользователям, вам нужна связь один-ко-многим. Для этого удалите UNIQUE со строки id_пользователя INT UNIQUE (Это относится к моему примеру) или с вашей конфигурации таблиц. Если хотите, могу дополнительно это описать
